# How can I let siblings' children respond to eachother?

Tags: css

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">meh</a></li>
<li><a class=target>aha!</a></li>
</ul>
```

This CSS would hopefully allow `aha!` to change when `meh` is focussed on

```
li a:focus ~ li a.target {

}
```

Of course it doesn't work because it is expecting an `a:focus ~ li` instead of a `li a:focus`

I have tried with `li>a:focus ~ li a.target` but it seems to make the same mistake, is there any way to group them so that they would produce the requested response? There doesn't seem to be a way to select a parent and crawl through the hierarchy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be a way to select a parent and crawl through
>   the hierarchy...

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that.

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but maybe this is it:

```
ul li:first-child:hover + li .target {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XXZLM/

Comment: Well I wanted something more flexible, but that still doesn't work if I change the `:hover` to `:focus` so that's not right.

Comment: Why are you [using `:focus`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus) when you want to "hopefully allow aha! to change when meh is *hovered* over"? That's the part I wasn't sure about.

Comment: Oh sorry! Let me change that!

Comment: What you're trying to do cannot be done with your current HTML structure. It doesn't work with `li:focus` because the `li` is never focused (the `a` is). There's no way to select a parent or "upwards", so you're out of luck. Here's a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XXZLM/1/

Comment: Well how come your example works with `:hover` but not with `:focus` then?

Comment: Because in my example, the `li` has `:hover` and is then hovered, so the selector works. When you change `li:hover` to `li:focus`, it breaks because the `li` is never focused - the `a` is.

Comment: If you change your HTML so that the `a` elements are siblings, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XXZLM/2/. So: [use JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XXZLM/1/), change your HTML, or give up :)

Comment: No but you didn't apply the `:hover` to the `li`, you applied it to the `li:first-child`, that's the `a` right?

Comment: `li:first-child` means "select the first child of the parent element (in this case, the `ul`) *if* it's an `li`". So in short, select the first `li` in the `ul`. It *does not* mean "select the first `a` in the `li`".

Answer (score 1):

```
ul:hover li a{background:red}
ul:hover li a.target{background:transparent}
```

Comment: Yes but the container `ul` does not respond to `:focus` which only the lowest level children accept